# How to use ImageDataGenerator with my own set of images for image augmentation

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

From [here](https://medium.com/towards-data-science/image-augmentation-for-deep-learning-using-keras-and-histogram-equalization-9329f6ae5085) 
it shows how to do image augmentation with an existing image set, `cifar10`.

How can I create an `ImageDataGenerator` with my own set of images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change your train_generator to `flow_from_directory()` and simply point to an image directory of your choosing:

```
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'your/data/here',
    target_size=(150, 150),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='binary')
```

You need to put your images in subfolders by class, i.e. `your/data/here/class1`, `your/data/here/class2` etc.

Keras docs [here](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#imagedatagenerator)